# No compatible GPU found, But nvidia prime is here?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I installed nvidia prime with driver 440 in kubuntu 20.04 and connecting my display with my intel iGP. But when I open blender, no such cuda compatible gpu found in settings.

Note:- I am able change nvidia X server setting & I am following [this doc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME#PRIME_GPU_offloading), so display is working. I am using blender 2.82a.

I am using environment variable (before I didn't)

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD="1"
__GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME="nvidia"
```

My screen is tearing (v-sync problem), but I am able to use dGPU on my games.(more then 120fps -- al-tho my display support only 60). Is there any way to set that env specific to an application? why still blender unable to detect my gt1030?

Comment: What is your Nvidia GPU model and have you checked that it is actually [supported for GPU rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware)?

Comment: and if your gpu is supported, try running blender as root

Comment: @RobertGützkow I alredy checked with windows. And root doesn't help.

Comment: use a current driver (450) from nvidia, I don't understand why you need to "prime". Do you have multiple cards (amd and nvidia) on the same computer?